# Moment.js - Round a duration

Tags: javascript, rounding, momentjs, duration

I have 2 datepickers (`from` and `to`), and I need to get the duration time between them, rounded by a variable value (e.g. 60 minutes).

I solved it, but maybe someone knows a shorter/nicer solution?

```
var duration = moment.duration(to - from),
roundedDuration = moment.duration(
    moment.utc(0)
    .add(duration)
    .ceil(ROUNDINGVALUE, ROUNDINGUNIT) - moment.utc(0)
);
```

My code does the following:

- Get duration between both times
- Add the duration to UTC time 0
- Round that date up to my desired value (60 minutes => full hours)
- Get the duration between that time and a new UTC time 0.

Is there another solution to round a moment duration?

Comment: What are `to` and `from`?

Answer (score -1):

Here i am assuming you have from/to as moment date objects with time as you looking for time duration.

```
var from = moment(),
    to = moment().add(2, 'hours'); // adding 2 hours here just for example sake

moment.duration(to.diff(from).asMinutes(); // 120     
moment.duration(to.diff(from).asHours() // 2, if you want in hours
```

Comment: i dont want do get only the diff duration, i want to round (ceil) that duration to a fixed other duration e.g.: diff duration between 2 dates is 2 houres (like your code) but i want to round them up to full 5 yours steps.

Comment: round up to what ? 2 hours would get round up to 5 hours ?

Comment: in my case i have to roud up to 1 hour (this value is variable and a moment duration). so how can i round values like: 2:37 -> 3:00 or 1:01 -> 2:00